# VBA : Find MAX in a range, change the other data to zero and repeat process

Tags: vba, excel

i am a newbie in vba so would like some advise on my current project.

I have a range of data as per below but with more materials numbers eg: 1002,1003,1004...

```
Material    Process     Time (mins)
 1001        a.1          0.00
 1001        a.2          0.00
 1001        a            0.50
 1001        b            0.70
 1001        c            1.00
 1001        d            2.50
 1001        e            1.00
 1001        f            0.30
 1001        g            0.50 
 1001        h            0.90
 1001        h.1          0.00
 1001        h.2          0.00
```

The 1st thing i need is for the program to find the max of the time from range A4:C11 and change the other time in the range < max to zero.

Then i need it to repeat the process for the rest of the data.
I have successfully did it by recording a macro (using IF function), but the macro is not so flexible as some data might have different range. so i hope to be able to get some help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all you want to create a dynamic range for each column. You'll need to add a row like to this your VBA code for each column you want to check. I'm using column B (Process) and C (Time).

```
LastRowB = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
...
```

Next we need to add the first value in a variable to compare it to the other values.

```
varC = Range("C2").Value
```

Now we can effectively check the variable to the other values and if the value is greater, we assign it to the variable.

```
'Look for the MAX value in this particular column
For i = 2 To LastRowC
   If Range("C" & i).Value > varC Then
       varC = Range("C" & i).Value
   End If
Next i
```

Once it's looped through `varC` should contain the highest value within that range. We can reuse the same loop, just change the conditions. Because you only want to keep the first MAX value, I'm going to work with another variable `varMAX`. `varMAX` is used to say 'Hey, I've already found a MAX value'.

```
'Set all values that don't match MAX to 0 and only keep the first MAX value
varMAX = 0
For i = 2 To LastRowC
   If Range("C" & i).Value < varC Then
       Range("C" & i).Value = 0
   Else
       If Range("C" & i).Value = varC And varMAX < 1 Then
           varMAX = varMAX + 1
       Else
           Range("C" & i).Value = 0
       End If
   End If
Next i
```

Now repeat this for each column you want.

PS: If anyone can tell me how to add decent formatting to my FOR loop (get the correct alignment), please tell me in a comment! :)

Comment: hi @CustomX, thanks for the help, i have some questions in the answer below *comment not able to accomodate the qs.. * hope u can help!

Comment: @Aqila, Ok so if the max is repeated only the first one (that I can do). I'm not sure what you mean with the Material part? Could you please explain further?

Comment: if the range of data is expanded, prev its only 1001.. then i added 1002,1003,1004,1005.. the max value will take the max from the total range of 1001 until 1005.. i need 1001 max, 1002 max, 1003 max.. so on..

Comment: @Aqila, you should edit your question because you don't mention that anywhere. Will the Materials column always be in the correct order? All 1001, then all 1002, all 1003, etc ?

Comment: no it wont be in the correct order. the material numbers might be 1111,1234,1215..

Comment: @Aqila, you'll have to ask that in a different question. I won't be able to help you with that. I'll update my answer so it only keeps the first MAX value.